# What is template handling for custom post type in wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i try to create a new custom types (name : guide). its already done, but i cannot get appropriate look for those type. i try several view name such as : template-guide.php, archive-guide.php, guide.php. but no one is called. its always go to index.php.

and also i check http://www.chipbennett.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/WordPressTemplateHierarchy.2011.11.11-1024x1016.png

i try check if its is_archive, it's return false. but when i try to execute is_home(), its return true. url query is ?post_type=guide.

thank you!

Comment: Are you setting the posts and/or pages to use custom templates? Please check within the edit-post window within the WordPress admin area, and confirm.

Comment: this is not a single post, but its view for entire new post type (guide)

Answer (score 0):

single-guide.php should solve it

Comment: no, i don't look for single post view. but something like archive of one of post type (which is in my case guide).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a new page template, like page-guide.php, assign that template to a new page (maybe called "Guides"), then add on that template the custom loop to display your custom posts.

Comment: yes, i also think about this hack. but i thought there is better way to display those page type?

Comment: I believe there's not, this is the cleaner solution I could find.